# PhD thesis plan

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I'm starting my PhD. My advisor's papers are not exactly the most beautiful works I've ever seen (it's a matter of taste), so I'm searching by my own some topics that could fit better with me. It's not that easy.

I've gave a glimpse to the modular forms, they seems attractive. My advisor likes algebraic geometry, complex geometry, if I talk about algebraic curves he's happy; so

1) I was asking my self: what is the connection between elliptic curves and modular forms? Can someone suggest me some reference?

2)Are there open problems in the intersection of modular forms/elliptic curves?

I like complex analysis in one variable, integral transforms, special functions, that kind of stuff. I like also algebraic arguments like groups, Galois and representation theory. I know it's a vague question, but it couldn't be different.

3)Is there any direction coming into your mind? Any suggestion?

Comment: Isn't the connection modular forms/elliptic curves essentially what Wiles worked on for his proof of Fermat's last theorem ? If I understand correctly, he proved one of the big conjectures in this field but only for the specific case he needed in the proof - so I'd guess there's a lot of work in that area; but I'm no expert so I'd wait for someone more qualified. Also Galois representations are closely linked to elliptic curves if I'm not mistaken, so that again is a sign that there's a lot to be said about what you mention

Comment: The first step for starting scientific work is to search yourself. For these topics there are really many survey works, which you will find quickly. Have you googled for books? See [Koblitz](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387979663?gclid=Cj0KCQjw_7HdBRDPARIsAN_ltcLOd28EznjBddHPeTV1WyRTDspXZFI5LrTKd27Ihreu4zIJc-S98fMaAtTOEALw_wcB), for example.

Comment: @Max Wiles's FLT proof was of the semistable case of what was then called the Taniyama-Shimura conjecture, but WIles also collaborated with others on a proof of the full conjecture, now known as the modularity theorem. The OP should definitely learn about that theorem if their interest is in the modular/elliptic connection.

Comment: @J.G. I didn't know (another proof that I'm not an expert, if one was needed), thank you for the info !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably already found in researching these topics online that the problem is not finding something to read, but knowing how to narrow it down. I recommend finding the most recent PhD theses you can that discuss one or more of these topics; many are readable online as PDFs. You needn't read entire theses, but their abstracts and literature reviews will reveal what if anything they can tell you about these topics and their connections. And if you find a thesis (or other piece of research, which may lack a literature review) that's actually contributed to such areas, they're likely to conclude with an acknowledgement of further-study-is-needed areas. Theoretically, that could give you ideas.

Comment: THANK YOU. I'm in trouble and I am grateful for your help.